# How do I calculate the dual map $\varphi^*$ of $\varphi$?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Linear map $\varphi :\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^3$ is given through matrix representation

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 4 &7 \\ 2&1 \\ 7&8 \end{pmatrix}$

Suppose the canonical bases in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ are assumed and $(\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3 )$ is the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^{3*}$. Compute $\varphi^*$ so-called dual map of $\varphi$ , which is defined by the representation matrix $A^R$, and show that this mapping with respect to the $\varphi $ fulfills property $\varphi^*:\mathbb{R}^{3*}\rightarrow$$\mathbb{R}^{2*}.$

Comment: From $\mathbf R^3$ to  $\mathbf R^3$, really?

Comment: Edited. Thank you @Bernard

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have written...

Comment: $A^T {}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

I suppose that, by the ‘*standard basis*’ of $\mathbf R^{3\mkern1.5mu*}$, you mean the dual basis of the canonical basis of $\mathbf R^3$, i.e. the canonical projections onto $\mathbf R$ $\;(x,y,z)\mapsto x,\,y,\,z$ respectively.

Let  $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2$ the standard basis of $\mathbf R^{2\mkern1.5mu*}$. One has to find the  coordinates of $\varphi^*(\delta_i)$ in basis  $(\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2)$.

Let $v=(x,y)=\bigl(\varepsilon_1(v),\varepsilon_2(v)\bigr)\in\mathbf R^2$ and apply the definition of $\varphi^*$:
$$\bigl(\varphi^*(\delta_i)\bigr)(v)=\delta_i\bigl(\varphi(v)\bigr).$$
Can you proceed from there?